# How to contol the height of blade in a vinyl cutter machine?

Tags: arduino, cnc

I have a machine that has 3 axis x,y,z.  The machine is a vinyl cutter.

The x and y axis are stepper controlled, but the z axis is a coil so my question is how does the manufacture control the z height.

I need to program it using an Arduino, the machine uses an IC marked A3955 to control the height.

Comment: [You start by looking up the datasheet of the A3955.](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A3955-Datasheet.ashx%3Fla%3Den%26hash%3D9D0C8A1031094F4C859AC5FF7AFE96D477DAE1AA)  Does it really use this chip?  Is it really a simple coil?

Answer (score 2):

Most Vinyl cutting applications do use a simple moving armature to raise and lower the cutting tip.
This means the cutting tip is pushed down with a fairly constant force when cutting, it's position (height) is NOT controlled. Using this method it can handle variations in the material thickness without problems.

If indeed the vinyl cutter does use the A3955, then you would have to either excise the signals from the controller board or build a new controller for the Z axis control.
The A3955 is used to provide accurate current control and the ability to pull/push a magnetic armature.
I assume for the X,Y axis you intend to build an Arduino controller for these and not break into the cutter control board. The same strategy for the Z axis would seem best.

The biggest problem you have is understanding the Z axis current profile they used. It may be quite complex and you'd need an oscilloscope and current probe (or series resistor) to really figure it out.

Comment: but the problem that I can't just pushed down as fair as possible because it might cut the carrier  paper under  the sticker you know  [link](https://blog.signwarehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/blog_Plotter-Blades_extention_300x184.jpg)  and for the current controller yes its hard I was trying for  the couple  days and I figure out that to control z is to push it down, then wait some time (depending on this time) the push it down again in different force in this way I can control the z height  but I think this way is not so efficient

Comment: @Ahmad As I said …"The biggest problem you have is understanding the Z axis current profile they used." You have to push hard enough to cut the softer vinyl but not hard enough to push through the backing. You could perhaps start by measuring the tip force with a very small scale. However as I also said you may need to directly measure the coil current profile or use a logic analyzer to read the profile fed to the A3955.D/A pins.